# FaxServer installed in docker on 0.0.0.0:8080 and how to access on Unbuntu 14.x from internet

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have installed [FaxServer](https://github.com/bludesign/FaxServer/blob/master/README.md) to my Ubuntu server.  It uses DOCKER.

It is up and running as follows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES

597d61ce2785        bludesign/faxserver:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bash -c…"   19 
minutes ago         Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   faxserver_vapor_1

6595fe5908c5        mongo:latest                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 
minutes ago      Up 6 minutes        27017/tcp                faxserver_mongo_1
```

I do not have access to apply any public IP numbers to the DOCKER. My main server in which DOCKER is running has access to the internet and hence has a public ip.

How can I run apache or something to access the FaxServer from the internet running on 0.0.0.0:8080?  The mongo is part of the FaxServer.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: check if the port 8080 is open 
simply try <instance-ip>:8080 what is the problem. I am not aware of faxServer. If the service needs webserver. You need to run the webserver too which you haven't

Comment: It’s so far not about having the port open or not.  I cannot figure out how to contact the docker instance with a private ip from the internet .

Comment: May be what you are looking for is port forwarding with which you can easily access the private ip from the internet

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You can use NGINX as a reverse proxy server (https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), and add an env-var called "virtual-host" to the container as follows:

   docker run -d -p 80808:8080 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=awesomefaxservice.com --name awesomefaxservice bludesign/faxserver

then configure a DNS to point to the machine ip, Once you have done that any requests matching the virtual host will be redirected to the container on the exposed port.

If you don't want to install a proxy and get a dns, check option 2.

2. You can configure the system proxy rules to accept incoming traffic from the internet and simple access your_static_ip:container_port

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be possible to add the main server IP to the docker instances and then access it via a subdomain like xxx.example?

Comment: I found this article:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-bind-multiple-domains-ports-80-and-443-to-docker-contained-applications

This is the commnand I think I am loking for:  docker run -d -p 80:80 coreos/apache /usr/sbin/apache2ctl   What is coreos/apache and /usr/sbin/apache2ctl   supposed to be syntax-wise?

Comment: @spreaderman as you can see the comments in that article refer to using nginx, also it's more appealing so you won't need extra dependencies on your service, making it more heavy and harder to maintain, for what you asked on your first comment I don't follow what you mean by main server IP, I guess it's just the docker host, but you can absolutely add subdomains to the reverse proxy, so all the DNS (and sub domains) point to the same ip and nginx manage the routing

Comment: The article's first solution is port binding and not related to nginx.  The second solution, which I want to avoid, is using nginx. Thanks.

Comment: if you don't want nginx you can go with my second suggestion. @spreaderman, even if you decided to use Apache it won't make a change if you don't make this step.

Comment: The docker app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 .  I create a subdomain called fax.example.com  My apache virtual host is now listening on 8080 as follows:

<VirtualHost fax.example.com:8080>

That works!

Thanks for all the suggestions.